# mssql 2008 - creating stored procedure using select into

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm new to Mssql 2008. In Oracle when im trying to create stored prod based on the value from another table i can use something similar like this;

```
Select username into temp_value from logintbl;
```

Then i insert the `temp_value` to my table. How do i achieve this in MSSQL? Any comments,reference or advice is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
DECLARE @Username nvarchar(100)
SELECT @Username = username FROM logintbl

INSERT INTO table1 (usernames)
VALUES (@username)
```